# How Can I Align These TextBoxes For My Website?

Tags: css

Recently, I've been trying to align my two text boxes for my website, but I couldn't figure it out. Do understand that I'm not knowledgeable in CSS like you are, but I need to know what to change so that they won't show up on the far left and unaligned. This is what it looks like on my website for some reason:

[http://i.imgur.com/zkxPBEl.png](https://i.imgur.com/zkxPBEl.png)

As you can see, it doesn't align properly, even when I try to center it using an online editor. Please help! Thanks!

```html
<!-- AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 --><form class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post">
<div style="display: none;"><input name="meta_web_form_id" type="hidden" value="604218668" /> <input name="meta_split_id" type="hidden" value="" /> <input name="listname" type="hidden" value="awlist4661276" /> <input id="redirect_56ab2ff33416d920a3c24dc4d8e140f4" name="redirect" type="hidden" value="http://bloggingnetworkonline.com/InternetMarketing/?page_id=133&amp;preview=true" /> <input name="meta_adtracking" type="hidden" value="My_Web_Form" /> <input name="meta_message" type="hidden" value="1" /> <input name="meta_required" type="hidden" value="name,email" /> <input name="meta_tooltip" type="hidden" value="name||First Name...,,email||Best Email..." /></div>
<div id="af-form-604218668" class="af-form">
<div id="af-body-604218668" class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element"><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534028"></label>
<div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: left;"><input id="awf_field-90534028" class="text" style="width: 200px;" tabindex="500" name="name" type="text" value="First Name..." /></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element" style="text-align: center;"><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534029"></label>
<div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: left;"><input id="awf_field-90534029" class="text" style="width: 460px;" tabindex="501" name="email" type="text" value="Best Email..." /></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer" style="text-align: left;"><input id="af-submit-image-604218668" class="image" style="background: none; max-width: 100%;" tabindex="502" alt="Submit Form" name="submit" src="https://hostedimages-cdn.aweber-static.com/MTE0ODQyNQ==/original/d316599087b84f9498e3854009bdad52.png" type="image" />
<div class="af-clear">We respect your <a title="Privacy Policy" href="https://www.aweber.com/permission.htm" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">email privacy</a></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element privacyPolicy" style="text-align: center;">
<div class="af-clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="https://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=bAwsTIwcbGwc" alt="" /></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
// Special handling for facebook iOS since it cannot open new windows
(function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('FBIOS') !== -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Twitter for iPhone') !== -1) {
        document.getElementById('af-form-604218668').parentElement.removeAttribute('target');
    }
})();
// ]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
(function() {
        var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
        if (!IE) { return; }
        if (document.compatMode && document.compatMode == 'BackCompat') {
            if (document.getElementById("af-form-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-form-604218668").className = 'af-form af-quirksMode';
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-body-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-body-604218668").className = "af-body inline af-quirksMode";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-header-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-header-604218668").className = "af-header af-quirksMode";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-footer-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-footer-604218668").className = "af-footer af-quirksMode";
            }
        }
    })();
// ]]></script>
<!-- /AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input Tags have different width settings.

style="width: 200px;" and style="width: 460px;"

Make these the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the solution your looking for? Your looking to have the name input field centre aligned with the next field. If you set the position to relative and set the left position to ((email width - name width) / 2) You'll end up with an equal distance on the left and right making it centred

So your layout becomes this

130px <--- 200px ---> 130px
<------------ 460px ------------>

```html
<form class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post">
<div style="display: none;"><input name="meta_web_form_id" type="hidden" value="604218668" /> <input name="meta_split_id" type="hidden" value="" /> <input name="listname" type="hidden" value="awlist4661276" /> <input id="redirect_56ab2ff33416d920a3c24dc4d8e140f4" name="redirect" type="hidden" value="http://bloggingnetworkonline.com/InternetMarketing/?page_id=133&amp;preview=true" /> <input name="meta_adtracking" type="hidden" value="My_Web_Form" /> <input name="meta_message" type="hidden" value="1" /> <input name="meta_required" type="hidden" value="name,email" /> <input name="meta_tooltip" type="hidden" value="name||First Name...,,email||Best Email..." /></div>
<div id="af-form-604218668" class="af-form">
<div id="af-body-604218668" class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element"><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534028"></label>
<div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: left;"><input id="awf_field-90534028" class="text" style="width: 200px; position:relative;left:130px;" tabindex="500" name="name" type="text" value="First Name..." /></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element" style="text-align: center;"><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534029"></label>
<div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: left;"><input id="awf_field-90534029" class="text" style="width: 460px;" tabindex="501" name="email" type="text" value="Best Email..." /></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer" style="text-align: left;"><input id="af-submit-image-604218668" class="image" style="background: none; max-width: 100%;" tabindex="502" alt="Submit Form" name="submit" src="https://hostedimages-cdn.aweber-static.com/MTE0ODQyNQ==/original/d316599087b84f9498e3854009bdad52.png" type="image" />
<div class="af-clear">We respect your <a title="Privacy Policy" href="https://www.aweber.com/permission.htm" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">email privacy</a></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element privacyPolicy" style="text-align: center;">
<div class="af-clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="https://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=bAwsTIwcbGwc" alt="" /></div>
</form>
<!-- /AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `style="margin: 0 0 0 13%;"` to your form tag it will be centered properly. or if you want then you can change the amount if it is not centering then too.. I hope this will help you :)

```html
<!-- AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 --><form  style="margin: 0 0 0 13%;" class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post">
<div style="display: none;"><input name="meta_web_form_id" type="hidden" value="604218668" /> <input name="meta_split_id" type="hidden" value="" /> <input name="listname" type="hidden" value="awlist4661276" /> <input id="redirect_56ab2ff33416d920a3c24dc4d8e140f4" name="redirect" type="hidden" value="http://bloggingnetworkonline.com/InternetMarketing/?page_id=133&amp;preview=true" /> <input name="meta_adtracking" type="hidden" value="My_Web_Form" /> <input name="meta_message" type="hidden" value="1" /> <input name="meta_required" type="hidden" value="name,email" /> <input name="meta_tooltip" type="hidden" value="name||First Name...,,email||Best Email..." /></div>
<div id="af-form-604218668" class="af-form">
<div id="af-body-604218668" class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element"><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534028"></label>
<div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: left;"><input id="awf_field-90534028" class="text" style="width: 200px;" tabindex="500" name="name" type="text" value="First Name..." /></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element" style="text-align: center;"><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534029"></label>
<div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: left;"><input id="awf_field-90534029" class="text" style="width: 460px;" tabindex="501" name="email" type="text" value="Best Email..." /></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer" style="text-align: left;"><input id="af-submit-image-604218668" class="image" style="background: none; max-width: 100%;" tabindex="502" alt="Submit Form" name="submit" src="https://hostedimages-cdn.aweber-static.com/MTE0ODQyNQ==/original/d316599087b84f9498e3854009bdad52.png" type="image" />
<div class="af-clear">We respect your <a title="Privacy Policy" href="https://www.aweber.com/permission.htm" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">email privacy</a></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element privacyPolicy" style="text-align: center;">
<div class="af-clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="https://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=bAwsTIwcbGwc" alt="" /></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
// Special handling for facebook iOS since it cannot open new windows
(function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('FBIOS') !== -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Twitter for iPhone') !== -1) {
        document.getElementById('af-form-604218668').parentElement.removeAttribute('target');
    }
})();
// ]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
(function() {
        var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
        if (!IE) { return; }
        if (document.compatMode && document.compatMode == 'BackCompat') {
            if (document.getElementById("af-form-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-form-604218668").className = 'af-form af-quirksMode';
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-body-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-body-604218668").className = "af-body inline af-quirksMode";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-header-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-header-604218668").className = "af-header af-quirksMode";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-footer-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-footer-604218668").className = "af-footer af-quirksMode";
            }
        }
    })();
// ]]></script>
<!-- /AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the container holding the div inline-block. And use "text-align:center" on the container holding that div. See code below. Hope it helps.

```css
.af-form {
  text-align: center;
  }
.af-body {
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
}
.af-clear {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 --><form class="af-form-wrapper" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post">
<div style="display: none;"><input name="meta_web_form_id" type="hidden" value="604218668" /> <input name="meta_split_id" type="hidden" value="" /> <input name="listname" type="hidden" value="awlist4661276" /> <input id="redirect_56ab2ff33416d920a3c24dc4d8e140f4" name="redirect" type="hidden" value="http://bloggingnetworkonline.com/InternetMarketing/?page_id=133&amp;preview=true" /> <input name="meta_adtracking" type="hidden" value="My_Web_Form" /> <input name="meta_message" type="hidden" value="1" /> <input name="meta_required" type="hidden" value="name,email" /> <input name="meta_tooltip" type="hidden" value="name||First Name...,,email||Best Email..." /></div>
<div id="af-form-604218668" class="af-form">
<div id="af-body-604218668" class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element"><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534028"></label>
<div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: left;"><input id="awf_field-90534028" class="text" style="width: 200px;" tabindex="500" name="name" type="text" value="First Name..." /></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element" style="text-align: center;"><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-90534029"></label>
<div class="af-textWrap" style="text-align: left;"><input id="awf_field-90534029" class="text" style="width: 460px;" tabindex="501" name="email" type="text" value="Best Email..." /></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer" style="text-align: left;"><input id="af-submit-image-604218668" class="image" style="background: none; max-width: 100%;" tabindex="502" alt="Submit Form" name="submit" src="https://hostedimages-cdn.aweber-static.com/MTE0ODQyNQ==/original/d316599087b84f9498e3854009bdad52.png" type="image" />
<div class="af-clear">We respect your <a title="Privacy Policy" href="https://www.aweber.com/permission.htm" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">email privacy</a></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element privacyPolicy" style="text-align: center;">
<div class="af-clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="https://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=bAwsTIwcbGwc" alt="" /></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
// Special handling for facebook iOS since it cannot open new windows
(function() {
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('FBIOS') !== -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Twitter for iPhone') !== -1) {
        document.getElementById('af-form-604218668').parentElement.removeAttribute('target');
    }
})();
// ]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
(function() {
        var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
        if (!IE) { return; }
        if (document.compatMode && document.compatMode == 'BackCompat') {
            if (document.getElementById("af-form-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-form-604218668").className = 'af-form af-quirksMode';
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-body-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-body-604218668").className = "af-body inline af-quirksMode";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-header-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-header-604218668").className = "af-header af-quirksMode";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("af-footer-604218668")) {
                document.getElementById("af-footer-604218668").className = "af-footer af-quirksMode";
            }
        }
    })();
// ]]></script>
<!-- /AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0.1 -->
```